# Web scraping using Selenium and chromedriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am looking at [**this**](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IBM) page. I am trying to use Selenium and chromdriver to scrape this data (shown by the red marker):

[image]

Here is my Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/ABC/chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IBM")
sleep(10)
estimated = driver.find_element_by_class_name("IbBox Ta(start) C($tertiaryColor)")
```

But the code does not get the `Est. Return` and after a long wait it returns this error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the best and fastest way to get the `Est Return` value from the page?

**UPDATE:**
Here is what I see if I use inspect element in Chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header plays an important role to fetch the value you are after, so make sure you have one. Given that this is how you get the desired content.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IBM"

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
est_return = soup.select_one("[class='Mb\(8px\)']").get_text()
print(est_return)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works nicely. How did you find the class? How do you know it should be `Mb\(8px\)`?

Comment: Class name containing braces should be escaped. The backslash ( \ ) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, I am not too familiar with this.

Comment: For example how can you extract `Near Fair Value` ?

Comment: Try this `soup.select_one("[class='Mb\(8px\)']").find_previous_sibling().get_text()`

Comment: Thanks again, that works as well.  Still, it is unclear to me how did you find out that we should use `class='Mb\(8px\)'`. If I right-click on chrome and look at the source page it is not there. Can you please explain how and where do you find the class name? Please explain this so I can accept your answer as a complete answer. Thanks.

Comment: Why you don't find it in that page is a real mystery. However, check out this ***[image](https://filebin.net/1w8w4h8uwpll6q1s)***

Comment: Thanks for the image. Ok I see that image now. I will update my question with that image. My question is that the Est. Return is inside a different `div`, and that `div` has this class: `IbBox Ta(start) C($tertiaryColor)`. Why did you use the class name for the outer `div`?

Comment: To get that specific output from that page you need to use any unique selector. Given that there is hardly any within `IbBox Ta(start) C($tertiaryColor)`, so I had to choose the parent which surely gives you the required result. Hope you got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with XPath instead, it should look like this:

```py
estimated = driver.find_element_by_xpath("*//div[@class='IbBox Ta(start) C($tertiaryColor)']").text()
```

Let me know how does it go! :D

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

...implies that the *Locator Strategy* you have used wasn't a valid expression.

---

To scrape the text **-6% Est. Return** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IBM')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Near Fair Value']//following::div[1]/div"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  -6% Est. Return
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```